# Wifi is Slow and Latent

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, internet, wireless-router

I have a Verizon FIOS package and their new version of the router. The internet is great on wired, but once I moved onto WIFI, specifically when I use it not next to the router, the connection turns to dialup.

I upgraded my own WIFI card on the laptop and also swapped on some big huge pair of 9dbi big antennas, my signal is very strong sometimes even FULL bars, but the speed jumps very rapidly and becomes unstable. But most of the time shows 11-13mbps.

But sometimes jumps to 1 or 2 mbps, and the connection feels like it's always at that speed, even streaming live video will have to be on LOW settings.

Don't even get me started on gaming performance... 120 ping normally and jumps to 400-500 spikes and have complete disconnects for over 10-15 seconds sometimes...

I tried different channel the WPA-2 encrypt , performance mode for N only, and even QOS settings or even banning all other connections. i don't get why the internet is this slow with such a good singal strength.

if anyone could give me some suggestions that would be great. Specially the past few days internet gets unusable.

I can't even finish the pingtest.net which is about 2000 ping and 1000 ms jitter with 8% packet lost..

the speedtest results gives 0.8mbps down and 0.2 mbps up...

Comment: You say especially when you're right next to the router.  What kind of distance do you have from your devices to the router?  Are you using any kind of range extenders or boosters (personally I have three for coverage in my house)?  What other wireless devices do you have in the area, i.e. cordless phones or other 2.4 / 5 GHz devices?    These are just some of things to look at.  Also details on your router would help, i.e. what band, frequency, channels used, etc. Signal strength does not equal quality (packet loss).

Comment: @defaultNINJA well its 2.4 MI424WR FIOS N Router REV. I, the distance is abit big.. but even when its right next to the thing, its performing poorly. one cordless phone but is never close to the router
u cant set frequency on these crapy routers

Comment: I'd try running [inSSIDer](http://www.metageek.net/products/inssider/) to see if there are other networks near you that could be causing interference.  Even if you've tried other channels, that doesn't mean you've disproven that it's other network's interference . . .

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you have interference on the radio channel bring used for the wifi connectivity.  Try simply changing the channel in the router and rebooting it and see if that helps.

Comment: Should be a comment.

Comment: yea thanks for reading... specially the part where i said "I tried different channel"